# what are some git branching and CI setup options for this scenario?

Tags: git, merge, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I work in an environment that is in its early stages of its CI/CD.  Their existing CI/CD process is unconventional.  Developers create feature branches and then merge the feature branches into the develop branch *before* deploying to QA.  Then the team lead triggers a deploy of the latest code in the develop branch for QA to test.

My main concern is that, traditionally, the develop branch contains code that has been QA approved.  A developer will typically "reverse merge" the develop branch into his feature branch before committing.  A reverse merge like this is typically low/no risk since all code in the develop branch has already been QA approved.

So consider the following scenario for the current process being used at my organization:

- DeveloperX is working on Feature1 for SharedComponent
- DeveloperY has fixed Bug1 that was blocking DeveloperX from finishing Feature1 for SharedComponent and has merged his code into the develop branch
- DeveloperZ has implemented Feature2 for SharedComponent and has merged his code into the develop branch
- DeveloperZ's Feature2 branch has a lot of bugs which end up breaking SharedComponent

So after DeveloperX does a reverse merge of the develop branch into his Feature1 branch, he will have DeveloperY's bug fix that was needed to unblock his completion of Feature1.  But DeveloperX will now have several bugs in SharedComponent based on DeveloperZ's Feature2 branch merge into develop which has not yet been tested by QA.

Mature CI/CD environments are set up to avoid this type of scenario.  What are the typical types of constructs used in CI/CD environments that are used to avoid this type of scenario?  What might be some easy options for avoiding this type of scenario in my current envrionment?  Seems like Bitbucket could be configured to merge into a separate "test" or "qa" branch after PR approval.  But additional separation/granularity would be needed here as well b/c QA might say that one feature in the qa branch passes whereas another feature in the qa branch fails.

I'm curious about common strategies that are normally used to handle this scenario.  I normally interact in this process from a feature developer role and there are typically proper constructs in place to handle this scenario so I don't need to even think about it.  But given the setup and process of my current environment, I need to be able to make recommendations for a better and more structured process.

Comment: Your post is likely going to get [flagged for being opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Having said that, in my opinion, [A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is probably the closest you can get to "industry best practices."

Comment: I think a common strategy is to emphasize the "C" in CI and not to go the time consuming detour via QA to receive feedback of your work. If DeveloperZ breaks the code this should be caught by tests that are automatically run at least daily, preferably even more frequently.